# Parsing 'Table of Contents' to get the correct page numbers

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, stringi

Here is a table of content:

```
df <- tibble(ToC=
             c("3.1 texta.............. 22",
             "3.2 textb     25",
             "section 6 ................. 50",
             "section 10.2       65"))
```

I want to extract the contents and their respective page numbers as two variables. I tried the following, but it's not working correctly.

```
library(tidyverse); library(stringr)
df_toc <- df %>%
  mutate(page = as.numeric(str_extract(ToC, "[0-9]+")))
```

The correct page numbers should be 22, 25, 50, and 65. How should I solve this?

Comment: Couple of comments: (1) no need for `library(stringr)` if you use `library(tidyverse)`; (2) better not to use `df` as a variable name to avoid confusion with function of the same name.

Comment: You are almost there ..you just need `$` in your regex indicating end of string. `df %>%
    mutate(page = as.numeric(str_extract(ToC, "[0-9]+$")))`

Comment: Ok. Thank you, Ronak Shah!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (digits at the end of a line):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(page = as.numeric(str_extract(ToC, "\\d+$")))
```

Comment: This is amazing!